# KSQL JOINS and TIME

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I need to identify customers who had a "successful login" within 10 minutes from a "failed login"
I created a Windowed KSQL TABLE of "failed logins"

```
CREATE TABLE table_Rule200_FailedLogins WITH (TIMESTAMP='LOGDATE') AS \
SELECT CUSTID,LOGDATE,LOGIP \
FROM STREAM_DEMO_EXTRACTED \
WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 10 MINUTES) \
WHERE Successful_Login = 'FALSE' AND LogType = '39' \
GROUP BY CUSTID,LOGDATE,LOGIP;
```

I created a STREAM of "successfull logins"

```
CREATE STREAM stream_Rule200_SuccessLogins as \
select * \
FROM STREAM_DEMO_EXTRACTED WHERE LogType = '39' AND Successful_Login = 'TRUE';
```

KSQL won't allow me to join a stream with a "windowed" table

Is there a workaround for this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about doing a stream-stream join, which isn't currently available in KSQL (but is coming).

For now, you'd need to use Kafka Streams to do this.

Comment: FYI: Stream-stream joins as well as table-table joins will be available in the upcoming June preview release of KSQL (in the next few days).